# Symfony doctrine not returning record when there is German Umlaut in where clause.

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am having a very strange issue on my live server, There is a search feature in my Application which fetches result from two tables using join, All good on the local machine but on the live server whenever I search for a word having German Umlaut, doctrine returns empty data set. I printed SQL query using getQuery and getParameters functions and ran that query directly into my DB and this query shows correct results as well. Collation and Charset are UTF8 for DB tables and in Symfony connect.

What should I check next? is this a known issue of doctrine?

Symfony Version: 3.1.0
Mysql: 5.6.x
Doctrine-ORM: 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check the runnable query it tries to run in the web debug toolbar instead of getQuery and getParameters?

Checking the query in the debug toolbar is more reliable since you will be able to check the query already parameterized.

Comment: Doctrine is converting umlauts into ascii codes. like WHERE (LOWER(r0_.status) LIKE 0x2562697474652077E3A4686C656E25 OR LOWER(r0_.status) IN ('bitte', 0x77E3A4686C656E) but when I print getParameters(), I can see the right word.